# Creating a Cartesian product of sections in Catch2

Tags: c++, catch2

I have some code:

```cpp
#include <catch2/catch_test_macros.hpp>

#include <iostream>

TEST_CASE("Section showcase") {
    {
        SECTION("A1") {
            std::cout << "A1 ";
        }   
        SECTION("A2") {
            std::cout << "A2 ";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "some intermedite code";

    {
        SECTION("B") {
            std::cout << "B1";
        }    
        SECTION("B1") {
            std::cout << "B2";
        }
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jbMsr9qz7)

I would like to get all combinations of these two blocks:

```
A1 some intermedite code B1
A1 some intermedite code B2
A2 some intermedite code B1
A2 some intermedite code B2
```

But catch2 seems just to go through the individual sections:

```
A1 some intermedite code
A2 some intermedite code
some intermedite code B1
some intermedite code B2
```

How can I create a "cartesian product" of two section groups?

Comment: I found a hacky way: Make the cart-product: `bool a1 = GENERATE(true, false); bool b1 = GENERATE(true, false)` and then use normal it-statements later

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/cjb5sP57P